# CodeIgniter; $this usage in non object context

Tags: codeigniter, php

I am trying to edit my `config/database.php` within my CodeIgniter project so that I don't have to keep changing the database information every time I push a new version to the server. To do the latter, I have created a `$debug` variable, shown below, which checks against the uri to see if the site is being run on my localhost machine (where I build the project before upload) or on the actual server.

Unfortunately in the database.php file, I don't have access to the `$this` variable, and as I am personally new to OOP in PHP, I am not entirely sure of a way around this. Please can you tell me how I can do so?

Thanks,

Max.

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in application/config/database.php on line 51

```
$debug = strpos($this->uri->config->item('base_url'), 'localhost'); //line 51

$db['default']['hostname'] = $debug == TRUE ? 'x' : 'y';
$db['default']['username'] = $debug == TRUE ? 'x' : 'y';
$db['default']['password'] = $debug == TRUE ? 'x' : 'y';
$db['default']['database'] = $debug == TRUE ? 'x' : 'y';
```

Comment: I don't know CI, but I'm pretty sure that there's a better way to define alternate database configurations. I think *that* should be your actual question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

Comment: @deceze I just saw your comment, can you give an example, and what's wrong with the current method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to a get an instance of the codeigniter object -

```
$CI = get_instance();
```

For older versions of php, use =&

Then, use `$CI` wherever you would normally use `$this`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `get_instance()` to get the `$this` variable.

```
$ci = get_instance(); // $ci replaces $this
echo $ci->config->item('base_url');
```

The `$this` variable is a special variable used in object oriented code, when you have classes - see [php.net](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for some background reading on it.

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is only for objects, you cannot use it outside an object. Best way to do this, I believe, is to exclude `database.php` file when you deploy. The IDE you use should have an option to exclude file from deployment.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple answer to this problem.

Read Environment section at:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

basically create two folders
application/config/production and 
application/config/development

and put one copy of your database.php in each folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and compare it with your server names (localhost or remote). There is a function in CI that checks for it:

```
$this->input-> server('SERVER_NAME')
```

As written above, you have to change the `this` if not in object context.