# encrypting user SMTP before sending to DB in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, encryption

I have this issue: trying to make admin panel and there i have the inputs of user and pass of SMTP account and i need to make it as secure as possible before sending it to DB, and i'm doing like this:

```
$config = array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => Settings_model::$db_config['smtp_host'],
'smtp_port' => Settings_model::$db_config['smtp_port'],
'smtp_user' => $this->encrypt->decode(Settings_model::$db_config['smtp_user']),
'smtp_pass' => $this->encrypt->decode(Settings_model::$db_config['smtp_pass']),
'smtp_timeout' => 30,
'charset' => "utf-8",
'newline' => "\r\n"
            );
```

and i got this error :
`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /application/helpers/send_email_helper.php on line 29`

for this lines:

`'smtp_user' => $this->encrypt->decode(Settings_model::$db_config['smtp_user']),`

`'smtp_pass' => $this->encrypt->decode(Settings_model::$db_config['smtp_pass']),`

Any ideas? i don't want to expose the pass and user in files.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all!

I resolved this from this answser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9321743

`$ci = get_instance(); // $ci replaces $this`

and now works!

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** use `$this` operator in a static method.

You should make use of `self::` instead of `$this` for static methods.