# PHP functions: Call to a member function function() on a non-object

Tags: php

I'm quite new to PHP so I don't know how to solve this error. I've been reading the related posts here, but as I said I'm too little experienced to know hot to apply similar solutions :(

Here's the thing: 
In my main php file I have:

```
require_once("SentDocument.php"); 
$sent = new SentDocument();
$sent->myfunction(param1, param2);
```

And in SentDocument.php

```
class SentDocument {
        public function myfunction (&$param1, &$param2, &$sError)
        { // inside goes an sql query using param1 and param2 
        }   
}
```

With this I'm getting:
Call to undefined function myfunction() in ... pointing to this line in my main php file:

```
$sent->myfunction(param1, param2);
```

The odd thing is: when writting in my main php file:

```
$sent->
```

the php editor I'm using shows in a context window myfunction() so I can pick it up .. this means SentDocument.php is well linked and the function is available, right?

So why do I get the error? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a million!

Comment: And the function is placed inside a class name right? Can you post the class name aswell. Maybe you have a typo or something, since it can't find the class. Don't trust your editor :p

Comment: Don't you need to change that to `&$sError = null` to make that parameter optional if you're not passing it in?

Comment: Have you tried debugging $sent using var_dump? This way you can see if your object is instanciated, this is probably the issue.

Comment: it's placed inside the class name and no typos, been copying and pasting :(

Comment: Another thing to note is that as of php 5.3.0 passing variables by reference will generate a warning. Because all variables will be automatically be passed as reference. So you don't need to '&' sign.

Comment: var_dump of $sent is NULL what does it mean?

Comment: @w00 No it isn't! That is just wrong. How would you change variable by reference then???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `myfunction` should be in a class to be able to call using an instance. So:

```
class SendDocument
{
    public function myfunction (&$param1, &$param2, &$sError)
    { // inside goes an sql query using param1 and param2 
    }   
}
```

BTW why are you adding those parameters by reference `&`. Do you need to change them inside the function.

Also: `$sent->myfunction(param1, param2);` will result in a syntax error. If `param1` and `param2` are strings you should encapsulate them in quotes (either double or single) of or they are variables they should have a dollarsign (`$`) in front of it. My guess is that they should be variable since yu are trying to pass them by reference to the function (The ampersand sign `&` in the function declaration).

Another thing you have three required parameters in that function, but you are trying to call the function with only two parameters. So you shoudl either provide the third parameter when calling the function or you should make the third parameter option (by giving it a default value).

In you case I would change the structure to something like the following (semi pseudocode):

```
class SendDocument
{
    protected $errors = array();

    public function myfunction ($param1, $param2)
    {
        // run query

        // if something went wrong
        if (!$recordset) {
            $this->addError($theError, $query);
        }

        return $recordset;
    }

    protected function addError($error, $query) {
        $this->errors[] = array($error, $query);
    }

    public function getLastError() {
        if (empty($this->errors)) return null;

        return $this->errors[0];
    }

}

require_once("SentDocument.php"); 
$sent = new SentDocument();
$recordset = $sent->myfunction('param1', 'param2');
```

Comment: yes, sorry it is inside a class, forgot to add it to my post, now is there. Same error.

Comment: @user712027 See my updated answer with more troubleshooting or just check out [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/j1Onif) to see that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means, that `$sent` is not an object. You code seems right at first glance so the error must be somewhere else you have not posted yet. I assume You defined the class `SendDocument`?

What echoes `var_dump($sent)`?

Two other notes:

1. You should leave out the `&` in your function arguments. `&` means "pass by reference", so you only use this if you want to modify the variables, which you don't need here.
2. Your method definition awaits 3 parameters, but you only pass 2. So if the third is optional you should give it a default value otherwise an error message is thrown:

   ```
   public function myfunction ($param1, $param2, $sError = null)
   ```

Comment: var_dump($sent) is NULL. Also I've deleted $sError and the & but no difference.

Comment: @PeeHaa: sorry, of course the `&` in the function call is deprecated, not in the definition itself. I removed the confusing sentence.