# Fatal error: Call to a member function truncate() on a non-object using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, fatal-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call to a member function on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

What is wrong with this line of code?

`$this->Post->saveField('slug', $this->Text->truncate(Inflector::slug($post['Post']['title']),25,array('exact'=>false,'html'=>false,'ending'=>'')));`

As it gives me the error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function truncate() on a non-object in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/12345/domains/jazz.com/html/app/Controller/PostsController.php on line 161`

Should I be using something else? Like `$this->request->data['title'];`

Comment: `$this->Text` is not an object. That is what the error message says. Everything else matters on what you want to do an how.

Comment: especially with helpers being used in a controller context.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate! Just because I'm getting the same error doesn't mean it's fixed with the same answer! In fact closing this would lose the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that `$this->Text` is not an object, and you can't call the `truncate` (or any other) method on it.

Is `Text` supposed to be a model? If you want to use several models in a controller you can add it to the `uses` array:

```
var $uses =  array('Post','Text');
```

If it's a component, you should add it to the `components` array.

You can use the `String` class if you are looking for the `truncate` method that TextHelper provides. See the example given for `String::truncate` here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html

Answer (score 0):

just add a condition to check whether $this->Text is available or not

```
if ($this->Text) {
       $this->Post->saveField('slug', $this->Text->truncate(Inflector::slug($post['Post']['title']),25,array('exact'=>false,'html'=>false,'ending'=>'')));
}
```