# problems with OOP, MySQL Class

Tags: php, mysql

class for MVC to return fetch_array/object results

> ```
>   class DbDriver{
>     private $connection;
>     private $query;
>     private $result;
>     public function connect()
>         {
>         $host             = 'localhost';
>         $user             = '';
>         $password         = '';
>         $database         = '';
>         $this->connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
>         $this->connection = mysql_select_db($database);
>         return TRUE;
>         }
>     public function disconnect()
>         {
>         $this->connection->mysql_close();
>         return TRUE;
>         }
>     public function prepare($query)
>         {
>         $this->query = $query;
>         return TRUE;
>         }
>     public function query()
>         {
>         if (isset($this->query))
>             {
>             $this->result = $this->connection->mysql_query($this->query);
>             return TRUE;
>             }
>         return FALSE;
>         }
>     public function fetch($type = 'object')
>         {
>         if (isset($this->result))
>             {
>             switch ($type)
>             {
>                 case 'array':
>                     $row = $this->result->mysql_fetch_array();
>                     break;
>                 case 'object':
>                 default:
>                     $row = $this->result->mysql_fetch_object();
>                     break;
>             }
>             return $row;
>             }
>         return FALSE;
>         }
>     }
> ```

returns

[Wed May 30 11:55:42 2012] [error] [client] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function mysql_query() on a non-object in /var/www/httpdocs/test/mysql.php on line 30

line 30

```
        $this->result = $this->connection->mysql_query($this->query);
```

ill go nuts. >.<

Comment: Interesting: You are talking about OOP and then you use the outdated `mysql`-extension ... You should use `MySQLi`, or `PDO_MySQL` instead.

Comment: `mysql_select_db` doesn't return what you think it does.

Comment: `$this->connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);` 
and `$this->connection = mysql_select_db($database); ` why you are using same variable again ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because mysql_query:

> Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure.

so $this->connection is not **object**.

Please use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) driver or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php), mysql_* extensions [will be deprecated in the future](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Good PDO [examples](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem

```
$this->connection = mysql_select_db($database);
```

`mysql_select_db` returns `bool`

But please take a look on PDO or mysqli