# Call a member function on a non object

Tags: php

i want to display informations about object `Activity` that the function `getCurrent()` from the `ListActivity` should returns. 
When i try it, it works perfectly, i have the information needed from the class, but, i have this error message on the top of the page :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdentifiant() on a
>   non-object in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/prototype/administration.php
>   on line 34

Line 34 is here :

```
  while($listActivities->next())
  {
     $current = new Activity();
     $current = $listActivities->getCurrent();
     echo $current->getId(); // line 34
  }
```

And this is the `getCurrent()` function which return an Activity object.

```
  public function getCurrent()
  {
     if(isset($this->activities[$this->current]))
        return $this->activities[$this->current];
  }
```

I don't understand why i have this problem since it returns me the object that i want. 
Please help me figuring it out. Thanks.

Comment: and what does your getCurrent() return when the isset fails? `NULL`? This isn't an object.

Comment: @bwoebi It returns something since i see the informations about the Activity in the page. It definitely not return null. Thank you for replying.

Comment: try to `var_dump()` `$current` before the echo...

Comment: @R00t - Then show us the correct code, because the code you've posted doesn't return anything if isset() fails, yet you're adamant it returns something; ergo the code you're showing cannot then be the correct code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $current->getId(); // line 34
Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdentifiant() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/prototype/administration.php on line 34
```

WhatEVER you think happens, or whatEVER you see in your page, if the error says $current is not an object, it is not. It might not be null, but it could also be an array or anything that is not an object.

Also :

```
$current = new Activity();
$current = $listActivities->getCurrent();
```

Doesn't really makes sense to me.

Use

```
var_dump($listActivities->getCurrent());
```

To see what it exactly returns, and trust what errors say.

EDIT : And you may not even be looking at the right php script acually : The error says "getIdentifiant" while the code says "getId". Make sure you're looking at the right piece of code and refreshing the right page.

Comment: Thank you for replying ! i wrote `$current = new Activity` becasue i thought the problem was that.   
But, it seems like `getCurrect()` is returning `'object(Activity)#7 (4) { ["id":"Activity":private]=> string(3) "fir...blablabla... } **NULL**'`. 
I guess the last object in the list is null, am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

first set `$this->current` after `$current = new Activity();` (maybe in constercture)

and you should return false if `!isset($this->activities[$this->current])`

**also** if you use `$current = $listActivities->getCurrent()` you lost your `Activity` object , it should save into another variable

here new code :

```
  while($listActivities->next())
  {
     $current = new Activity();
     if(  $listActivities->getCurrent() )
        echo $current->getId(); // line 34
  }


  public function getCurrent()
  {
     if(isset($this->activities[$this->current]))
        return $this->activities[$this->current];
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: Nice ! It worked. Actually, the function `getCurrent()` was always returning 'null' for the last object of the list. So the real problem is `while($listActivities->next())` which should not call the actual last object (or null). 
But thank you, your help is much appreciated :)