# Cannot fetch using sqli inside function

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to sqli ,just started learning oops . I have this code in my **db.php**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

Another file **func.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
function get_users()
   {        

     $sql="SELECT * from users";    
     $result=$db->query($sql);    

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $data[]=$row;
            }

     return $data;
}
```

`var_dump(get_users());`

`Error : Undefined variable: db`

and when i use

`global $db;` inside function

`Error : Call to a member function query() on a non-object in`

What is the problem here and how can i correct it ?

Comment: Try `return get_users($data);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- same non-object problem

Comment: Try putting what I wrote above, outside your last closing brace. @user2894116

Comment: @Fred-ii- when i dont pass $db i get both the errors above & when i pass $db i get `Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc()`. after using  `return get_users($data);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's how the site works, grooming a list of canonical questions rather than a scatter poop of unrelated ones.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Your answer was probably downvoted by YCS.

Comment: @user2894116 [**Here's a Pastebin file I made**](http://pastebin.com/cpnZsMK3) they can't downvote that. I hope it serves you well.

Comment: `To People who added the question as DUPLICATE` I tried finding my answer in the link . If i had an answer or found something useful i woudnt have asked the question in first place. Don't know if the site provide REP for adding a duplicate tag. I think when asking question we should also put a list of links and write `Hey people i dint find anything useful here so my question is not duplicate.` Please dont downvote a question if someone wants to learn

Comment: @Fred-ii- tnx buddy.. i found the error.

Comment: @user2894116 You're welcome and glad to hear that. What was the error? I'm curious.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think it was my localhost. Deleted the file , wrote the same code again and now its working :)

Comment: @user2894116 Right on, a happy ending after all, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making it `global`, pass the `$db` as a `function` parameter and you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object) answer for the error (`Error : Call to a member function query() on a non-object in`) you get after you are using `global` keyword.

Passing `$db` as a function parameter...

```
function example($db) {
   //Use the $db here
}
```

While you call the `function`, pass your `$db` variable like `example($db);`

Also you might like to read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Alien I'm not using a class for database connection so when i try this get_users(mysqli $db); according to the link you provide it gives same error

Comment: @YourCommonSense I answer on more sensible questions than you do :D

Comment: @YourCommonSense we are not good coders like you . So we will keep on asking silly questions to learn more.

Comment: @user2894116 you'd better learn how to use google. It is not that hard

Comment: @YourCommonSense This site is always my last option.