# Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

> Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in  C:\xampp\htdocs\c\application\models\usermodel.php on line 138

```
public function new_pass(){

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $pass1 = $this->input->post('pass1');
    $pass2 = $this->input->post('pass2');

    $result = $this->db->where('email', $email)->update('user',[
        'pass1' => $pass1,
        'pass2' => $pass2,
    ]);

    if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r($result == TRUE);
    return;
remove these line from your code

Comment: remove `return;` before `$result->num_rows()` !!

Comment: it's already removed :( not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

Comment: print_r($result); and check what result you have

Comment: 1 means true :) but not working :(

Comment: use $this->db->affected_rows() for update

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For insert and update query we use  [**$this->db->affected_rows()**](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html)

Also change your query too

```
public function new_pass(){

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $pass1 = $this->input->post('pass1');
    $pass2 = $this->input->post('pass2');
    $this->db->set('pass1',$pass1);
    $this->db->set('pass2',$pass2);
    $result = $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->update('user');

    $afftectedRows = $this->db->affected_rows();
     if ($afftectedRows == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```