# CODEIGNITER call to a member function num rows on boolean

Tags: php, codeigniter

please i have an issue with codeigniter. when i try to log here is the result:

### Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in D:\xampp\htdocs\procurementSys\application\models\login_model.php on line 19

Below tho code of the relative file:

```
  <?php


  class Login_model extends CI_Model {

//this function checks whether the username and the password is in the database or not
public function check_login($username, $password){

    $this->db->select('username, password, status');
    $array = array('username' => $username, 'password' => sha1($password),'status' => 'active');
    $this->db->where($array);
    $query = $this->db->get('user');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1) // if the affected number of rows is one
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//this function returns the status of the user to be used in authentication
public function user_login_data($username, $password){

    $this->db->select('status');
    $array = array('username' => $username, 'password' => sha1($password));
    $this->db->where($array);
    $query = $this->db->get('user');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1) // if the affected number of rows is one
    {
         $row = $query->row();
         return $row->status;
    }
  //        else
  //        {
  //            return false;
  //        }
}


public function user_role($username){ // this function gets the user's role from the database
     $this->db->select('role');
     $this->db->where('username', $username);
     $query = $this->db->get('user');
     $row = $query->row(0);

     return $row->role;
}

public function department($username){ // this function gets the user's department from the database
     $this->db->select('department');
     $this->db->where('username', $username);
     $query = $this->db->get('user');
     $row = $query->row(0); // returns the first row with an array of objects that is stored in the row variable

     return $row->department;
}

public function get_user_id($username){ // this function gets the user's department from the database
     $this->db->select('userID');
     $this->db->where('username', $username);
     $query = $this->db->get('user');
     $row = $query->row(0); // returns the first row with an array of objects that is stored in the row variable

     return $row->userID ;
}

public function fullname($username){
     $this->db->select('firstName, secondName');
     $this->db->where('username', $username);
     $query = $this->db->get('user');
     $row = $query->row(0);
     return $row;

  //            foreach($query->result() as $row) // returns the query as an array of objects
  //           {
  //                $data[] = $row; // equates the array of objects to an array variable
  //           }
  //        
  //           return $data;
   // }
}

 }

 ?>
```

I kept  searching for a solution and found this post ([Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155636/call-to-a-member-function-num-rows-on-boolean)) . It gave me an idea but no real help. thanks

Comment: plz mention error in which function ????

Comment: It seems that the variable `$query` that you are trying to use an an object and call a method on is in fact a boolean, not an object. You can just use var_dump to see for your self, to debug it. In your case this usually means that the query above failed, so you should research error handling.

Comment: indeed, var_dump@$query returned BOOL(FALSE). how to solve that. what should i include as code to help me cheking the errors?

Comment: `db->get()` can return FALSE which usually indicates a problem with the sql statement. For me it is usually something in the `where` part of the statement. I have gotten in the habit of using `if($query){..` before using it, eg. `$row = $query->row();`

Comment: public function user_login_data($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('status');
        $array = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => sha1($password)
        );
        $this->db->where($array);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        if ($query) {
            if ($query->num_rows() == 1) 
            {
                $row = $query->row();
                return $row->status;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

Answer (score 4):

I got this error with MySQL Strict Mode enabled. When I disable Strict Mode, error disappeared.

To check this mode is already enabled

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

To make it disabled

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: I think this is a temporary solution. When we restart mysql again we will face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this for the count:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where($your_conditions);
$num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this **

```
//this function checks whether the username and the password is in the database or not


public function check_login($username, $password){

$this->db->select('username, password, status');
$array = array('username' => $username, 'password' => sha1($password),'status' => 'active');
$this->db->where($array);
$query = $this->db->get('user');
$result = $query->result();

if($result->num_rows() == 1) // if the affected number of rows is one
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CODEIGNITER send boolean as result if there is not result 
for example as per your method

```
public function check_login($username, $password){

$this->db->select('username, password, status');
$array = array('username' => $username, 'password' => sha1($password),'status' => 'active');
$this->db->where($array);
$query = $this->db->get('user');

if($query->num_rows() == 1) // if the affected number of rows is one
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

If there is no data in table it send False while we are expecting some object on which we can work so before calling **$query->num_rows()**  check if it is an object or not so code can be like :

```
 $query = $this->db->get('user');
    if(is_object($query)){
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) // if the affected number of rows is one
    {
        return true;
    }
        }else{  
        return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like that. It will work smoothly.

```
if($query !== FALSE && $query->num_rows() == 1) // if the affected number of rows is one
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```