# PHP MSSQL num_rows() not working with sqlsrv driver in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm getting the following error on a simple query that's supposed to return a number of rows:

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean
>
> Filename:
>   /var/www/cfc-dev/docroot/project/system/database/DB_query_builder.php
>
> Line Number: 1428

I'm using Codeigniter 3.1.9. I recently started using PHP7.2 and also sqlsrv driver to connect to a MSSQL database.

In some other post, someone mentioned that scrollable should be set to an option different than **SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD** so I dump the value of $this->scrollable in sqlsrv_driver.php and found out that its value is **buffered**

```
/**
     * Execute the query
     *
     * @param   string  $sql    an SQL query
     * @return  resource
     */
    protected function _execute($sql)
    {
        echo $this->scrollable; die();
        return ($this->scrollable === FALSE OR $this->is_write_type($sql))
            ? sqlsrv_query($this->conn_id, $sql)
            : sqlsrv_query($this->conn_id, $sql, NULL, array('Scrollable' => $this->scrollable));
    }
```

Not quite sure why it's failing. Any other queries that don't include num_rows() are fine so far.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your query? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the query and the code which failed. From the error message it looks like the query failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue! Apparently, sqlsrv driver does not seem to convert double-quoted strings into single-quote. So:

```
$tmp = 'SELECT * FROM tmpTable WHERE tmpName="test"';
```

when executing this query an error was being returned which was evaluated by Codeigniter as FALSE. I've got the same application in two different instances, one with PHP5.6 and the other with PHP7.2. With the PHP5.6 (different driver) instance I don't have this issue, only with PHP7.2 and sqlsrv driver. I assume the driver for 5.6 converts

```
$tmp = 'SELECT * FROM tmpTable WHERE tmpName="test"';
```

to

```
$tmp = "SELECT * FROM tmpTable WHERE tmpName='test'";
```

Answer (score 0):

All your `SELECT`queries will work with your method, but I guess you're also excecuting an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` or `DELETE` or else with the same method, in those cases you should use instead `$this->db->affected_rows()`

You can see a reference in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155636/call-to-a-member-function-num-rows-on-boolean). Also a bit more of code and the example of your query would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

*Test other method for count row. `$query->count_all_results();` or `$query->affected_rows();`*

Answer (score 0):

It is always difficult to answer without actual source code, but these explanations may help you.

The error, that you receive (I hope that we are talking about the same CodeIgniter version), is in public function `count_all_results($table = '', $reset = TRUE)`, when `if ($result->num_rows() === 0)` is executed.
The -> syntax is to access property/method on object. Using it on boolean does nothing but triggers an error. Variable `$result` holds the return value of `$this->query()` function. 
The `query()` function returns a database result object when “READ” type queries are run, which you can use to show your results. 
When “WRITE” type queries are run it simply returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on success or failure.
You can try to echo `$result` just before that `$result->num_rows()` call to see the actual value.

So, possible reasons for such an error may be the execution of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement or wrong T-SQL statement. 
Try to replace [count_all_results()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=count_all_results#CI_DB_query_builder::count_all_results) with [affected_rows()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=affected_rows#CI_DB_driver::affected_rows) for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements.
Also you may check the T-SQL statement with SQL Management Studio.

About `$scrollable` property. You are right that [sqlsrv_num_rows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-num-rows?view=sql-server-2017) requires a client-side (buffered), static, or keyset cursor, and will return `FALSE` if you use a forward cursor or
a dynamic cursor. But this can't be a reason for your error, because `$scrollable` member of class `CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver` has default value `FALSE` or `SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED`, and `num_rows()` member of class `CI_DB_sqlsrv_result` doesn't seems to raise an error.