# SSH/Crontab returning fetch_object() on a non-object

Tags: php, cron

I've been developing a MMORPG game lately. And are almost done, just creating the daily cron..

I've got the following code:

```
// Bank Interest
$res = $db->query("
    SELECT uid, 
           id, 
           rm_days,
           bank
      FROM sys_users
      LEFT JOIN sys_users_stats ON sys_users.id = sys_users_stats.uid
") or die($db->error);

while ($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
    $multiply = ($row->rm_days >= 1) ? 0.04 : 0.02;
    $interest = ($row->bank >= 15000000) ? ceil(15000000 * $multiply) : ceil($row->bank * $multiply);

    $res = $db->query("UPDATE sys_users_stats SET bank = bank + $interest");

    $rjdRPG->addEvent($row->uid, "You have gained $$interest bank interest.");
}
```

Everything works ok, it even does send me the event in the game:

> You have gained $24 bank interest. 01 Dec 2015 09:20 PM

Only SSH/Crontab is returning an error if I run it manually, (testing purposes) It's returning:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in /home/RJDGaming/tm/crons/daily.php on line 22

But it is updating the `bank` column to the correct amount. And sends out a notification, so all seems ok, but i'm not sure how I should solve that PHP Fatal Error as everything is working fine. `$db->error` doesn't return anything, so i'm a bit lost here.

A finger pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you update `$res` in the loop:

```
$res!   while($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
            $multiply = ($row->rm_days >= 1) ? 0.04 : 0.02;
            $interest = ($row->bank >= 15000000) ? ceil(15000000 * $multiply) : ceil($row->bank * $multiply);

$res!       $res = $db->query("UPDATE sys_users_stats SET bank = bank + $interest");

            $rjdRPG->addEvent($row->uid, "You have gained $$interest bank interest.");
        }
```