# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in {path}

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here is my code:

```
$money = $db_con
->prepare(" SELECT SUM(asker_amount) asker, SUM(responder_amount) responder
            FROM money WHERE post_id = ? AND author_id = ? AND paid IS NULL")
->execute(array($ques_id, $author_ques_id))
->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$asker_amount = $money['asker'];
$responder_amount = $money['responder'];
```

It doesn't execute and throws this error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in {file path} on line 5 (`->fetch( ...`)

Ok what's wrong? And how can I fix it?

**Note:** That query works as well, I've tested it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: The `execute` function returns a boolean: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @pgmann Do you mean I have to fetch `$money` instead of chaining it to `execute()` ?

Comment: Obviously it DOESN'T work well here, as some stage of that process is failing and returning a boolean false. In general, never EVER chain DB calls like that. It assume nothing will ever fail, which is exactly the wrong attitude. Queries can fail even if the sql syntax is 100% perfect. **ALWAYS** assume failure, check for failure (at every stage), and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
$query = $db_con->prepare(" SELECT SUM(asker_amount) asker, SUM(responder_amount) responder
        FROM money WHERE post_id = ? AND author_id = ? AND paid IS NULL");
$query->execute(array($ques_id, $author_ques_id));
$money = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$asker_amount = $money['asker'];
$responder_amount = $money['responder'];
```

You should be assigning `$money` the result of the final `fetch` only.

Comment: `fetch` is a method of `PDOStatement`, not `PDO`

Comment: @vp_arth Sorry, fixed it!

Comment: and still doesn't check for errors. if the prepare fails and returns boolean  false, then over subsequent statement is useless anyways.

Comment: @MarcB May you please write an answer for my question?

Comment: @MarcB writing error handling code for the every single query is a bit overkill. Especially given that properly configured PHP can report errors by itself.

Comment: I added an example anyway

Comment: @YourCommonSense: true, but if you fail in stage 1, then there's no point in failing in stages 2->n either.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Agreed .. Also that's interesting, usually  you are disagree with supper-reputation-users thought.

Comment: @pgmann would you ever use this kind of code that you added recently? Really?

Comment: @MarcB this is what exceptions exactly are for.

Comment: @YourCommonSense you mean the error checking one? Or my entire answer? I don't follow...

Comment: I mean recent addition you made with extremely laborous error checking code that tripled the amount of code written. To me it's a bit overkill when error handling code is 2 times bigger then the code itself. Don't you think so?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah. As I mentioned, quick but not very streamlined. And pretty redundant due to previously mentioned error logging. You're obviously the expert here (just read your profile!); would you include any error checking at all?

Comment: Not in case you only need to report it. Because PDO can report its errors by itself. You have to write a handling code only if you have a certain handling scenario in mind. Otherwise just let PHP report it usual way.