# Couldnt grab div element with a specified class name using simple_html_dom?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using `simple_html_dom`, i am having issues grabbing a `div` with a class name specified below is the `code!`

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html='
   <div class="user-info ">
    <div class="user-action-time">
        answered <span title="2016-06-27 20:01:45Z" class="relativetime">Jun 27 at 20:01</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user-gravatar32">
        <a href="/users/25355/david-mulder"><div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/09e3746cf7e47d4b3b15f5d871b91661?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" width="32" height="32"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="user-details">
        <a href="/users/25355/david-mulder">David Mulder</a>
        <div class="-flair">
           '; 
echo $html->find('div[class=user-details]',0);
    ?>
```

What am i doing wrong here i am getting error **Call to a member function find() on string in**

Thanks!

Comment: you need to work on your question's title. Edit: Oh, this as per original http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38918520/1 just in case people ask ;-)

Comment: It's like trying to attract/catch mice with cheese; they actually don't eat "cheese" ;-) but they love bran muffins though!!! @StackB00m

Comment: its usefull comment @StackB00m, if you use proper title, than u will get more answers.

Comment: Maybe you have the 'Call to a member function find() on string' error because $html is a string.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object

Comment: You need to call `str_get_html()`.

Comment: `var_dump($html->find('div[class=user-details]',0));` chk this, you will get the solution..

Answer (score 5):

You are tying to use Simple Html Dom to parse an html string.

Do not assign your html string to `$html` variable.
Assign it to an other, like `$html_string`.
Then use `$html = str_get_html($html_string)`
and
`echo $html->find('div[class=user-details]',0);`

Comment: Oops yes that was so stupid of me i forgot doing this  thanks for reminding     :)

Answer (score 2):

You trying to call object method on a string variable. It should works:

```
$html = str_get_html('<div class="user-info ">
    <div class="user-action-time">
        answered <span title="2016-06-27 20:01:45Z" class="relativetime">Jun 27 at 20:01</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user-gravatar32">
        <a href="/users/25355/david-mulder"><div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/09e3746cf7e47d4b3b15f5d871b91661?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" width="32" height="32"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="user-details">
        <a href="/users/25355/david-mulder">David Mulder</a>
        <div class="-flair">');
```