# Issue deleting parent and his sub-categories with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to convert mysqli code to PDO way but I run into an issue.

It should behave: If deleted main parent delete his sub categories also, so that there are no "orphans" left in database.

The main parents are parent 0 in [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BZw2.jpg),  while sub categories are linked with parents ID.
**This is working mysqli example :**

```
// Delete
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])) {
    $delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete'];
    $delete_id = sanitize($delete_id);
    /* Deleting a parent and its children to avoid orphaned categories in the database. */
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '{$delete_id}'");
    $category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($category['parent'] == 0) {
        $db->query("DELETE FROM categories WHERE parent = '{$delete_id}'");
        header("Location: categories.php");
    }

    $db->query("DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = '{$delete_id}'");
    header("Location: categories.php");
}
```

**What I have tried with PDO way:**

```
//delete Category
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){
$delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete'];
$delete_id = sanitize($delete_id);

//Deleting sub-categories if parent is deleted
 $sql= $veza->prepare ("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '$delete_id'");
 $result = $sql->execute();
 $category = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($category['parent'] == 0){

$sql = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE parent = '$delete_id'";
$sql->execute();
 }

 $dsql=$veza->prepare("DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = '$delete_id'");
 $dsql->execute($_GET);
  header("location: categories.php");
}
```

I can't find the solution.

I have Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean

Comment: You will need to fetch from the statement object. Execute will return boolean value. In your case it ia the `$sql` var

Comment: If I am doing it correctly this gives me Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on string , inside if code block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

Comment: Because after that you replaced the var with string and directly execute it. It goes like this, prepare -> bind parameters -> execute -> fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by doing :

```
//delete Category
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){
$delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete'];
$delete_id = sanitize($delete_id);

//Deleting sub-categories if parent is deleted
$sql= $veza->prepare ("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = $delete_id");
$sql->execute(array('delete_id' => $delete_id));
$category = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($category['parent'] == 0){

$sql= $veza->prepare("DELETE FROM categories WHERE parent = $delete_id");
$sql->execute();
```

}

```
$dsql=$veza->prepare("DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = '$delete_id'");
$dsql->execute($_GET);
 header("location: categories.php");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try google prepared statement.

You have boolean in the $result

Usage:

`$prep = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?");`
**The *?* is not replaced!**

Then use: `$prep->bind_params('i', $id); $prep->execute()`
And the result: `$result = $prep->get_result();`
Check if it is not *false*.

Comment: after trying to do code line :  $sql ->bind_params('i','$id');  I get : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_params().

Comment: params('i','$delete_id') if I understood correctly it replaces with the '?' after binding

Comment: Well, you need to have established connection to the DB via PDO (`$conn = new mysqli(host, usr, pass, db)`), Then need to call $conn for preparing and then call var with that prepared statement. Next, do not use ' ' when you are parsing arguments to the bind_params (except that first one, which is definition of var types)

Comment: I am using PDO way, not mysqli (the above mysqli code is example that works on mysqli way and below is my code), I have established connecting inside configuration.php with PDO way, and included it in my categories.php (file that I work on now).